# How to find cursor row in TextArea in JS when it has soft-wrapped lines?

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a textarea which I interact with using jQuery. I have some custom keydown event handlers. To make my interactions smooth I could use a function that returns "current cursor row".

One might think that there's a simple solution (proposed on countless SO questions)...

1. get current cursor position (cross browser plugins exist)
2. get TEXTAREA value substring up to that cursor position
3. count newline characters ('\n') in that substring

Problem? This doesn't work when textarea is soft-wrapped. Counting "\n" will produce numbers that are too low.

Question: how do I get the actual precise cursor row number in soft-wrapped textarea? (Precision is key to make my interaction smooth.)